# Setting profile edit icon on profile image

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I tried to use a profile edit icon on the profile image in android Kotlin. I am using card view to show image in circle view .but when I use edit icon at the corner of that circle it shows the part of the icon that is on the image but hides the part that is out of the image.
please help how to set it on image.

[image]

here is my code

```
         <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="60dp">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile_img" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Edit_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/edit_photo"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/edit" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Share the design required and your output design?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your code with `FrameLayout` and tweak your margins accordingly for the expected result.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="60dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/Profile_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/Edit_image"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/edit" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @shb answer, here is what i used!

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameProfileImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileImage"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_bg"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                app:civ_border_width="10dp"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
        </FrameLayout>



        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/frameProfileImage"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/frameProfileImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameProfileImage"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/editProfile"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/edit_profile"
                android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

happy coding...